# Is it possible that the Android translucent navigation bar "stains" the navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navigationbar

Due to some "Full Screen" requirements of a screen, I'm temporarily hiding the status and navigation bars when showing a window and, when done, I'm showing them again. This goes pretty well but it leaves me with this weird situation:

[image]

**On the left**, we see the bottom of the navigation drawer before hiding and showing the *translucent* navigation bar and

**on the right**, we see how it looks after the operation. It looks as though the translucent bar left a stain on the navigation drawer! If wondering, if I use a different navigational system (eg. 2- or 3-button), the stain is as big as the new navigation bar:

[image]

The methods used to hide and show the system UI (status and navigation bars):

```
    /**
     * Use this method to (temporarily) hide the status bar and the navigation bar
     */
    private fun hideSystemUI() {
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION)
        window.decorView.apply {
            systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
        }
    }

    /**
     * Restore the status and navigation bars
     */
    fun showSystemUI() {
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION)
        window.decorView.apply {
            systemUiVisibility =
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR
                } else {
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
                }
        }
    }
```

The situation persists until I restart the Activity that hosts the drawer.

Comment: Yeah, the same problem happened to me too. Really annoying one.